# How to specify the first run time AWS CloudWatch Rate Expression?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a Lambda Function that needs to be invoked biweekly on Sunday at 10am. I used the rate expression to set `14 days` as the rate period. However from the official documentation, I couldn't find a way to specify the `Sunday at 10AM` part. How can I make that happen?

Comment: Did you find answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do this you need to use a cron expression instead for the CloudWatch event.

The cron schedule `0 10 ? * 1 *` will cause the CloudWatch event to trigger every Sunday at 10 AM UTC. Be aware that regardless of your region that the cron will always evaluate in UTC so you may need to adjust the times to match your local region.

More information is available in the [cron expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, although the tricky part is that I need to run it every _other_ Sunday and not every Sunday. Could you suggest a cron expression that addresses that?

Comment: Rather than specifying the first run time of a rate expression, what actually is the first run time of a rate expression. Let's say I have a `rate(1 day)`, when would this be executed after creation? Just randomly within the next 24 hours? Or can I somehow estimate when it it would execute?